# Laravel 5 relationship of three models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Orders Table

```
 id   total        created_at
 ---+------------+--------------
 2    1500.99      2017-02-02
```

Items Table

```
 id   order_id    product_id   quant
 ---+-----------+------------+-------
 66    2              5          1
 67    2              6          2
 68    3              5          2
```

Products Table

```
 id   name        created_at
 ---+------------+--------------
 5   PC Intel    2017-02-02
 6   PC AMD      2017-02-02
```

Models

```
//Order Model
class Order extends Model{
 public function items(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
 }
}

// Item Model
class Item extends Model{
 public function producto(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Product');
}
} 

// Product Model
class Product extends Model{
 public function item(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Item');
 }
}
```

I want display Product name of relationhip models. For example I have

```
 $order = Order::with('items')->find($id);
```

But How I can add third Model for print name of product?? For example for print this

```
$order->items->product->name //"PC Intel"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$order->items` returns a collection. You cannot access properties.

Instead, you have to loop through all objects in the collection

```
foreach($order->items as $item) {
    $item->product->name;
}
```

Perhaps you should add products to your eager loading

```
order = Order::with('items.producto')->find($id);
```

Comment: Thank u, with this line you helped "Order::with('items.producto')->find($id)"

Comment: If my answer helped, please don't forget to mark it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Given your tables, **Item** should be like this:

```
// Item Model
class Item extends Model{
    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }

    public function order(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
}
```

For retrievenig product name you shoud know that items() return a collection so:

```
$order->items[0]->product->name //"PC Intel"
```